# mysql how to join these tables?

Tags: mysql, join

I have several tables: models, products, specs, pictures and stores.
They are associated as follows:

Each product belongs to (model, store)
Each picture belongs to (product)
Each    spec belongs to (product)

I need a list of products,

> > with the store they belongs to (by product.store_id)
> >     where product.model_id=some_id
> >     ONLY if there are specs for the product  (by spec.product_id)
> >     ONLY if a product has pictures (by picture.product_id)

What type of query do I need?

thanks

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition is very complete and can be translated quite literally:

```
select
  -- Selecting all fields of product and store. 
  -- You can refine this by only listing the fields you need.
  p.*,
  s.*
from
  -- need a list of products,
  product p
  -- with the store they belongs to (by product.store_id)
  inner join store s on s.store_id = p.store_id
where
  -- ONLY if there are specs for the product (by spec.product_id)
  exists
    (select
      'x'
    from
      spec ps 
    where
      ps.product_id = p.product_id) and
  -- ONLY if a product has pictures (by picture.product_id)
  exists
    (select
      'x'
    from
      pictures pp 
    where
      pp.product_id = p.product_id)
```

Comment: If you check my query, it will return the rows which OP wants

Answer (score -1):

Try this::

```
Select * from 
from 
product p
inner join model m on (p.model_id=m.id)
inner join store s on (p.store_id=s.id)
inner join picture pc on (p.picture_id=pc.id)
inner join spec sp on (p.spec_id=sp_id)

where product.model_id=some_id
GROUP BY product.id
```

Comment: Common mistake. Joining all tables will cause the query to return multiple rows. For instance, if you got 3 pictures and 10 specs, 30 rows are returned for each product.

Comment: a `select distinct p.*, s.*` would solve this problem... but it could also make the query slower

Comment: The addition will make it work, but the query is less obvious, less easy to expand and it violates standards, making it incompatible with other databases. I wouldn't use this MySQL trickery.